# How to stop my code from going into an infinite loop counting from 8 to 9 and back to 8?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make my display work by writing a little program that counts from 1 to 10, using `_switch cases_`,  and then make an LED blink every time the counter hits 0, 6 or 9 at the same time. Whenever it hits either 0 or 9 it should then count back down or up depending on if it's at the bottom or top. How do I make that work with my current code?

```cpp
int COUNT=0; //count integer for å telle 0-10 inc.

void setup() {
  for (int i=2;i<9;i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT); {
      // setter alle pins til output
      pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  switch (COUNT) {
    case 0: // Når den teller seg opp til 0, viser den 0 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH); // skrur på LED lyset - GRØNN
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW); // skrur av LED lyset - GRØNN
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      break;
    case 1: // Når den teller seg opp til 1, viser den 1 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
      break;
    case 2: // Når den teller seg opp til 2, viser den 2 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      break;
    case 3: // Når den teller seg opp til 3, viser den 3 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      break;
    case 4: // Når den teller seg opp til 4, viser den 4 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      break;
    case 5: // Når den teller seg opp til 5, viser den 5 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      break;
    case 6: // Når den teller seg opp til 6, viser den 6 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH); // skrur på LED lyset - BLÅ
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW); // skrur av LED lyset - BLÅ
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      break;
    case 7: // Når den teller seg opp til 7, viser den 7 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
      break;
    case 8: // Når den teller seg opp til 8, viser den 8 på disp
      digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
      digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
      break;
    case 9: // Når den teller seg opp til 9, viser den 9 på disp
      *things*
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH); // skrur på LED lyset - RØD
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW); // skrur av LED lyset - RØD
      delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
      break;
    break;
  }
  if (COUNT<10) {
    COUNT++;
    delay(1000); // teller opp hvert 1000ms
  }
  if (COUNT==10) {
    COUNT=9; // hvis den teller opp til 10, reseter den til 9
    delay(128);
    COUNT--;
    delay(1000);
  }
  if (COUNT==-1) {
    COUNT++;
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your `if (COUNT==10)` case, you set `COUNT` to 9 then decrement it, what else would you expect to happen? After you do that it's 8 which is less than 10 and will be incremented as before

Comment: I don't _exactly_ understand how coding works, which is why I'm asking how to _not_ make it count up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing a lot of the less meaningful code (at least when it comes to the question at hand) it looks like you want something similar to this:

```
int COUNT=0;
int change = 1;

void setup(){...}

void loop() {
    switch (COUNT){
        // cases 0-9:
        // Do something
        // break;
    }

    if(COUNT == 9) { change = -1; }
    if(COUNT == 0) { change = 1; }
    COUNT += change;
}
```

Where you specify a delta for each iteration (1 means incrementing, -1 means decrementing), and then each iteration you add that change to actual move up or down.

The only change you need then is to adjust the delta to go in the opposite direction when you reach one of the ends, in your case 0 and 9.

Comment: I changed my code to use this system, but now it only counts from 0, jumps straight to 6 and then straight to 9, but now it counts down properly?

Comment: By jumps, i mean it skips counting from 0 to 1 then 2 etc, it counts straight from 0 to 6, and then it counts up to 9 again. I don't think the problem lies in my switch cases because they work fine, it's just the counting doesn't seem to work.never mind, your counting sytem _didn't_ delay itself, properly like the old system I used, though it sussed out my code, so thank you.

Comment: @Encore Ah, I see, I removed any delays in your if statements at the end, you'll need to add your `delay(1000)` back in, apologies

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar code:

```
nt ports [] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};  // Digital PINS: used for display controll.
  int my_display [10] [7] ={      // Array with values of digital pins.
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,0},    // 0
  {0,1,1,0,0,0,0},    // 1
  {1,1,0,1,1,0,1},    // 2
  {1,1,1,1,0,0,1},    // 3
  {0,1,1,0,0,1,1},    // 4
  {1,0,1,1,0,1,1},    // 5
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,1},    // 6
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0},    // 7
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},    // 8
  {1,1,1,0,0,1,1},    // 9
  };


void setup(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){     // Set all digital pin in OUTPUT mode.
    pinMode(ports[i], OUTPUT);
  }  
}

void loop(){
 digitalWrite(9,LOW);              // Pin 9 control the display dot.
 for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ ){       // This loop numbers array.
   for(int j = 0; j<7; j++ ){      // This loop pins array.
    digitalWrite(ports[j],my_display[i][j]);    // Set Value to pin in function of number.
    }
 delay(1000);                      // Refresh time
 }

// Now start reverse count. And put visible the display dot.
 digitalWrite(9,HIGH);

 for(int i = 9; i>=0; i-- ){
   for(int j = 6; j>=0; j-- ){
    digitalWrite(ports[j],my_display[i][j]);
    }
 delay(1000);
 }
}
```

In my code, if you want reverse the count only need change the limit of loops and only need put the blink code at the end of loops.

PD: You said that "***ED blink everytime the counter hits 0, 6 or 9 at the same time it should then count back down and reset itself***" How is posible go to 9 if you reverse your count in 6?

Comment: It doesn't reset at 6, let me edit the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: could you try to comment in the code, my english isnt that good but I think I'll be able to read it.